# getting the root device?

Tags: linux, grep

I am trying to `grep` `lsblk`:

```
lsblk | grep '/'
```

The only issue is it returns me this:

```
└─sdb1      8:17   1   7.3G  0 part /
└─sdc1      8:33   1   7.6G  0 part /media
```

Which is great except I only want the root device being returned (`sdb1`) but i dont want to `grep` for `sdb1` because in the future it might not be the root device.

what would be the best way for me to get the root device without any extras?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Just add a `$` to denote the end of the line in `grep`:

```
lsblk | grep '/$'
```

Comment: I shall do but I have to wait for a few minutes before i can choose an answer .. 2 minutes left..